# OutofMemoryError, bitmap size exceeds VM budget. in a frame animation

Tags: android, performance, android-animation

I have an `AnimationDrawable` that loads few frames from the drawable resources, but on some devices I get `OutofMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget.`
Now I've read the [Displaying Bitmaps Efficiently](http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/index.html) guide but I can't relate it to my case?

```
if (animation == null)
        animation = new AnimationDrawable();

    for (int i = 0; i <= numOfFrames; i++){
        int resourceID = 
                context.getResources().getIdentifier(frameName + i, "drawable" ,
                        context.getPackageName());
        animation.addFrame(context.getResources().getDrawable(resourceID), 
                frameDuration);
    }
    animation.setOneShot(false);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
        pb.setBackground(animation);
    else
        pb.setBackgroundDrawable(animation);

    animation.start();
```

Comment: You should  find out the available VM memory and then subsample your bitmaps accordingly. Why is this not relating to your case?

Comment: @type-a1pha Do you mean not displaying all the frames in case there is no memory left?

Comment: It can be an alternative or complementary solution. But I was meaning loading in memory a smaller version of your stored bitmaps.

Comment: @type-a1pha they are pretty small already, I guess I'll just have to do something alternative. thanks anyway. How can I release those frames I've already used? I case I'd like to display the animation only once, and not in a loop. there seems to be no `animation.releaseFrame` or anything alike.

Comment: Do you have a memory leak? Are you recycling old animations?

Comment: @user1132959 Sometimes, but how can I recycle? When I'm done using the animation. I just stop it and turn `animation` to `null`

Comment: Wait, how many frames are we talking here? You might not even have to dispose of animations. I was thinking of bitmaps.

Comment: @user1132959 about 40

Comment: @RCB And what are the dimensions of each frame? 64x64? 128x128?  Also, which devices are you getting this error? What are their screen resolutions?

Comment: @user1132959 128X128, Galaxy S 480 x 800.

Comment: That's still only going to be less than 3 MB of RAM.  Is this the only animation? How many times is this piece of code called?